# Choice based conjoint with SPSS

Tags: spss, stata, multinomial-distribution, conjoint-analysis

Is it possible to run a Choice Based Conjoint analysis (preferably with also no-choice option) with SPSS? Do I need a particular package for that? if not possible with SPSS is it possible with Stata?

If not possible would it be the same running a Multinomial Logistic regression?
How could I get the info I get with conjoint (importance of attributes, simulation of preference etc) with MNL?

Thanks in advance,

Fabio

Comment: SPSS has an in-built option for plain conjoint only. I'm not aware if somebody among the users has written a syntax for choice-based conjoint. Try to google or ask your question in SPSS communities.

Comment: But if I run MLN with SPSS do I get the same results I would get with CBC? I am interested in importance of attributes (that would be IVs in MLN) and share of preference.

Comment: You can do CBCA with [rologit](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rrologit.pdf) in Stata. Can you clarify what you mean by no-choice option?

Comment: For no choice option I mean showing 4 products to the respondents and also give them the opportunity to chose none of the 4 product. Does CBCA suffer from IIa hypothesis?